# Can't receive telemetry thingsboard

Tags: mqtt, thingsboard, telemetry

I'm testing Thingsboard since some month and today I started having some problems receiving telemtry.

I'm using ESP8266 with DHT11 and the code that appear on the tutorial:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/samples/esp8266/temperature/

I've been using differents variants of this code to send any kind of data and always worked ok.

Now I can't receive anything from any device.

Port 1883 open.

AP: Correct, the device connect with thingsboard and send telemetry.

TOken: ok.

But in the asset I can't see any telemetry.

Some suggestion?

Many thanks!

Comment: Which thingsboard version are you using? Are there any messages in the logs leading to your problem? What is the value of 'lastConnectTime' server attribute?

Comment: is the live demo version. Now is working again and I did anything. It looks like there was a problem in the demo. Thanks!